# Calculate coordinates of intersection

Tags: javascript, canvas, intersection

I’ve got two lines and I’d like to calculate their intersection point.
See http://jsfiddle.net/magglomag/7sydgkt6/1/

Red line coordinates

`P1 ( 150, 0 )`

`P2 ( 125, (stepsY+150)/2 )`

Blue line coordinates

`Q1 ( 150, 150 )`

`Q2 ( 125, (stepsY)/2 )`

—

I found out that you have to derive linear functions like `f(x) = m*x + n` for each line to calculate the intersection.

—

**Step 1**

To get the slope m:

`m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`

Red line slope

`mP = - ( (stepsY + 150) / 50 )`

Blue line slope

`mQ = - ( ((stepsY/2) - 150) / 25 )`

—

**Step 2**

The second step would be to define the y-intersect n:

Red line y-intersect

`nP = ( (stepsY + 150) / 50 ) * 150`

Blue line y-intersect

`nQ = ( ( (stepsY/2) - 150) / 25 ) * 150 ) - 150`

—

**Step 3**

Now I can derive the functions:

Red line function

`f(x) = mP * x + nP`

`f(x) = ( - ( (stepsY + 150) / 50 ) * x) + ( (stepsY + 150) / 50 ) * 150`

Blue line function

`f(x) = mQ * x + nQ`

`f(x) = ( - ( ( (stepsY/2) - 150) / 25 ) * x) + ( ( (stepsY/2) - 150) / 25 ) * 150 ) - 150`

—

**Step 4**

Now I need your help!
The next step would be to equal both function like `mP * x + nP = mQ * x + nQ` but I don’t get it.
It would be great if anyone can help out!

—

**JS**

```
var mouseX  = 0;
var mouseY  = 0;

var stepsY  = 75;
var stepsX  = 100;

var pageY = 0;
var pageX = 0;

$(window).on({
    load: resizeCanvas()
});


function resizeCanvas() {
    document.onmousemove = function(e) { 
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;
    }
}


var loop = setInterval(function() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    if (canvas.getContext) {

        stepsY += ( ( 125 + parseInt(-mouseY / ($(document).height() / 85 ) )) - stepsY ) / 12;
        stepsX += ( ( 125 + parseInt(-mouseX / ($(document).width() / 46 ) )) - stepsX ) / 12;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if ( window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ) {
            canvas.width = 600;
            canvas.height = 300;
            canvas.style.width = "300px";
            canvas.style.height = "150px";
            ctx.scale(2,2);
        } else {
            canvas.style.width = "300px";
            canvas.style.height = "150px";
        }

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo( 150, 0 );
        ctx.lineTo( 125, (stepsY+150)/2 );
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.stroke();        

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo( 150, 150 );
        ctx.lineTo( 125, (stepsY)/2 );
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.stroke();   

    }    

}, 20);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So set your equations equal to get

```
mP*x + nP = mQ*x + nQ
```

then solve for x to get

```
mP*x - mQ*x = nQ - nP
(mP - mQ)x = nQ - nP

x = (nQ - nP)/(mP - mQ)
```

(If (mP - mQ)=0 then the lines are parallel and there is no point of intersection)
and the y coordinate would be

```
y = mP * x + nP     or     y = mQ * x + nQ
```

The two equations should yield the same y-value (up to rounding error).